# find key of smallest value in a dictionary

Tags: python

I have written this method which is suppose to find the value which has smallest value (doing a Kaggle exercise)

```
candidate_max_leaf_nodes = [5, 25, 50, 100, 250, 500]
# Write loop to find the ideal tree size from candidate_max_leaf_nodes
mae_results_dict_val = {}
for max_leaf_nodes in candidate_max_leaf_nodes:
    mae_result = get_mae(max_leaf_nodes,train_X,val_X,train_y,val_y)
    print('mae for %d is %d'%(max_leaf_nodes,mae_result))
    mae_results_dict_val[max_leaf_nodes]=mae_result

   
# Store the best value of max_leaf_nodes (it will be either 5, 25, 50, 100, 250 or 500)

best_tree_size2 = min(mae_results_dict_val,key=mae_results_dict_val.get) #works but I copied this code
```

what does `min(mae_results_dict_val,key=mae_results_dict_val.get)`  do?

Comment: Please provide a [mre]

Comment: Why? The problem is not that the code doesn't compile or doesn't work. I am asking explanation of a syntax or meaning of an API. I don't see any reason to provide a functional prototype.

Answer (score 1):

`min()` return the value in the first value in sorted. key designate the way to sort the values. `key=mae_results_dict_val.get` means the list will be sorted by values of the dictionary.